# Auto Increment ID FlasList React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-table

I want to add a column with auto incrementing ID, my json object doesn't have property: 'id' to do it easy, so I don't know what to do

```
<View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.row}>№</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}>Название</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}>Значение</Text>
            </View>
            {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>ID</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>{item.address}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />
            )}
</View>
```

So when I render my item my first column should be auto rising

```
1  |  item.name  |  item.address
2  |  item.name  |  item.address
3  |  item.name  |  item.address
```

Whole code, if this is matter:

```
export default function FlowMeter({navigation}) {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getObjects = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getObjects();
    }, []);


    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.row}>№</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}>Название</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}>Значение</Text>
            </View>
            {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>ID</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />
            )}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

renderItem also return an index so that is what you want ?

```
return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.row}>№</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}>Название</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}>Значение</Text>
            </View>
            {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>index</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />
            )}
        </View>

    )
```

Comment: ohh, thanks, I really didn't know about that